# Iterating over dataframes and adding items from a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Quite new to python for data analysis, still a noob.

I have a list of pandas data frames (+100) who's variables are saved into a list.

I then have the variables saved in another list in string format to add into the dataFrames as an identifier when plotting.

I have defined a function to prepare the tables for later feature engineering.

I want to iterate through each data frame and add the corresponding strings into a column called "Strings"

```
df = [df1, df2, df3]
strings = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']


def mindex(df):
# remove time index and insert Strings column 
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.insert(1, "Strings", "")

    # iterate through each table adding the string values 
    for item in enumerate(df):
        for item2 in strings:
            df['Strings'] = item2


# the loop to cycle through all the dateframes using the function above
for i in df:
    mindex(i)
```

When ever I use the function above it only fills the last value into all of the dataframes. I would like to note that all the dataframes are within the same date range, as I have tried to use this as a way to stop the iteration with no win.

Can anyone point me in the right direction! Google has not been my friend so far

Comment: I do not fully understand the objective. Are you trying to add to each df a column with the corresponding name of df? i.e. df1 should have a column named "Strings" that would take the value "df1" across all rows?

Comment: Yes exactly that. df1 would have a column with all rows saying 'df1', df2 = 'df2' etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line `df['Strings'] = item2` you assign variable item2 into entire column df["Strings"].
So first iteration assigns "df1", second assigns "df2" and ends with "df3" and this is what you see finally.

if you want to have in column *Strings* entirely populated by "df1" for df1, "df2" for df2 etc. you have to:

```
def mindex(dfs: list, strings: list) -> list:
    final_dfs = []
    for single_df, df_name in zip(dfs, strings):
        single_df = single_df.copy()
        single_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        single_df.insert(1, "Strings", "")

        single_df['Strings'] = df_name
        final_dfs.append(single_df)
    return final_dfs

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
strings = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']

result = mindex(dfs, strings)
```

Few takeaways:

1. if you define list of dfs, name it dfs (plural), not df.

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
```

2. If you iterate through pandas DataFrame, use df.iterrows(). It will generate indices and rows, so you don't need to apply **enumerate**.

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    ....
```

3. if you use variable in for loop that is not going to be used, like in your example **item**, use underscore instead. It is good practice for useless variable:

```
for _ in enumerate(df):
    for item2 in strings:
        df['Strings'] = item2
```

Comment: Don't understand some of the things you did (new concepts to study) but it worked and will allow me to go on with my project.

if I wanted to save the results to the existing datafframes and not merge them into one new one, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure what you would like to achieve, but if you finally want to have input list of dfs with modified dfs, you can just overwrite variable: `dfs = mindex(dfs, strings)`

Answer (score 1):

```
df = [df1, df2, df3]
strings = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']

for s, d in zip(strings, df):
   d['Strings'] = s
```